# Twig: elegant way to output array elements in a grid of N columns with if condition

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I'm using Timber & Twig to write a Wordpress theme. It is my understanding that the idiomatic way of outputting posts in a grid with N columns is with the `batch` filter:

```
{% block content %}

{% for row in posts | batch(3) %}
    <div class='grid-3'>
    {% for post in row %}
        <div class='col'>
            {% include ['tease-'~post.post_type~'.twig', 'tease.twig'] %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

How would one go about using the `batch` filter with an `if` condition such that you only output, for example, top level posts in a hierarchy?

(Condition would be `{% if not post.parent %}`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. If you’re looking for an elegant way, I recommend going a different one:

Whenever I can, I don’t filter posts in Twig, but in PHP, before the posts are being passed to the template. With Timber, there are multiple ways you can go:

### 1. Adapt the query

Using the proper [parameters for WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters), you can often select only the posts you need.

```
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts( array(
    'post_parent' => 0
) );
```

### 2. Filter the query results

Sometimes using a lot of parameters in WP_Query can make your query slow. For performance reasons it’s sometimes better to query more posts that you later filter with PHP.

```
$posts = Timber::get_posts();

$filtered = array();

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_parent === 0 ) {
        $filtered[] = $post;
    }
}

$context['posts'] = $filtered;
```

or

```
$posts = Timber::get_posts();

$posts = array_filter( $posts, function( $post ) {
    return $post->post_parent === 0;
} );

$context['posts'] = $posts;
```

**A small caveat:** The default query uses the amount of posts defined in your WordPress Backend under Settings > Reading > *Blog pages show at most*. When you filter the returned posts, you might end up with less posts than you intended.

### 3. Use and overwrite the default args

As [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21613/dan) mentioned in the comments, with #1 one would have to build up the whole `WP_Query` arguments again, if one is on a special page, say an archive page.

To get all the arguments that the main query uses and overwrite them with our own parameters to later use them in `Timber::get_posts()`, we can use the handy [wp_parse_args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_args/) function. We pass our new arguments as the first parameter and the query variables of the main query as the default parameters to overwrite.

```
global $wp_query;

// Set query args before posts are queried in get_context()
$args = wp_parse_args( array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_parent' => 0,
), $wp_query->query_vars );

$context = Timber::get_context();

$posts = Timber::get_posts( $args );
$context['posts'] = $posts;
```

### 4. Use `pre_get_posts` action hook (The WordPress way)

The default WordPress way to adapt the main query is to use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action hook. While this is probably the cleanest way to go, it’s not really convenient to use.

The `pre_get_posts` action hook needs to be defined in `functions.php`. If you define it in any template file (like page.php or archive.php) it will be too late. The disadvantage here is that you have to use conditionals (`$query->is_main_query()` etc.) to make sure that the changes you make are only applied where it makes sense. Inside the query, you can then set/reset the query vars that you want to change.

```
// In your functions.php

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_front_page() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'page' );
        $query->set( 'post_parent', 0 );
    }
} );
```

It’s much more convenient if you can set query vars in the template file where you will actually use them. That’s why I would prefer #3 over #4. I’ve run into debug sessions where I had a query acting weird, until I realized there was a `pre_get_posts` interfering.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the second form for filtering the query results. I find that to use #1 elegantly, Timber would need to have a way to _override_ the current query with just the additional parameters you'd want, as to not build the _entire_ WP_Query object in `get_posts`.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, unfortunately you can’t use the `pre_get_posts` filter with Timber, as you normally would when altering the main query. I added a solution #3 accordingly, which might suit you better. However, I don’t know how elegant it is.

Comment: That's great! This is very useful, thank you for it, and for the caveat with filtering the posts after the query. If it's not too much to ask, could you expand on not being able to use `pre_get_posts` with Timber? I seem to be able to set a custom number of posts per page (by overriding the `posts_per_archive_page` query var) and then use them in Timber.

Comment: @Dan Well apparently I was wrong. You *can* use `pre_get_posts` with Timber. I made the mistake of trying to use it in a template file instead of adding it to `functions.php`. So I learnt something myself, today :), glad you asked about it. I added solution #4 accordingly.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for being so thorough.